# gettext cant send to database with edit text

Tags: php, android, database

Unable to get text from edittext and send it to database. I'm able to upload image successfully but not with edittext.

SQL code :

```
$gambar_g=$_POST['gambar_g'];
$deskripsi_g = $_POST['deskripsi_g'];
```

and i'm using sql INSERT INTO statement and this is my android code :

```
 public static final String KEY_IMAGE = "gambar_g";
 public static final String KEY_TEXT = "deskripsi_g";
 ivImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
 des = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.desimg);
 ivGallery.setOnClickListener(this);
 ivUpload.setOnClickListener(this);
 desk = des.getText().toString();
```

class do in background :

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
  RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
  HashMap<String,String> param = new HashMap<String,String>();
  param.put(KEY_TEXT, desk);
  param.put(KEY_ID_LW, sid_lw);
  param.put(KEY_ID_F, id_f);
  param.put(KEY_IMAGE, image);
  String result = rh.sendPostRequest(UPLOAD_URL, param);
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged 'php'? Looks more like Java to me.

Comment: What happens when you try? Any errors? Anything in the logs?